# MySQL query skipping 001 numbers

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is a follow up to my previous question that was answered here - [Determine the next number in database query with while loop in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46940206/determine-the-next-number-in-database-query-with-while-loop-in-php)

If I have a product tab

```
products TABLE
==============
ABC001
ABC002
ABC003
ABC005
==============
```

and use this

```
SELECT SUBSTR(t1.id, 4) + 1 as POSSIBLE_MIN_ID
FROM products t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * 
    FROM products t2
    WHERE SUBSTR(id, 1, 3)='ABC' AND SUBSTR(t2.id, 4) = SUBSTR(t1.id, 4) + 1
) LIMIT 1
```

I get the result of 4. However if I have the table looking

```
products TABLE
==============
ABC005
ABC006
ABC007
ABC008
==============
```

It gives me a result of `9`. If I have none in the table it gives me a result of `2` not `1`. And if I add the `ABC001` in it works fine. Why is that and is there a way to fix it so it picks up the 1 as well? How can I have it work properly without having the `ABC001` in there?

Thank!

Comment: can you not use the snippets for something like this? please edit your post. Use indents and/or `<pre></pre>`.

Comment: I've added a ` to them. They're just number results so not sure what needs to the <pre> but more than happy to add more if it makes it easier to help.

Comment: ...someone did it *for you*.

Comment: Perhaps they didn't load the first time you saw this question. I added snippets for the 3 things the first time I asked the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5b0f1a92-4cda-4b67-9baf-ef02108f58db/view-source look at the source; you were using the snippets codes. Code needs to be indented and preformatted text/code needs to be set with `<pre></pre>` tags.

Comment: Guys, We should focus on the solution of the question rather than formatting. He can have some formatting classes later.

Comment: oh okay I apologize. Still fairly new in Stack Overflow but I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Thanks! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't undertand the question. What is your goal? Why do you mix strings with mathematical operations?

Comment: In the previous question, I mention I basically have a product number system which needs to determine the next product number. So if I have product numbers ABC001, ABC002, ABC004, I'd like it to pick up the ABC003 which it does. Unfortunately it doesn't work properly if there's no ABC001. Does that answer your question?

Comment: This is not how you should use MySQL.

Comment: @DanFromGermany this is not how I first did it, but people were suggesting in the other question that I make SQL do all the work instead of PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want the first unused 'ABCnnn'. So if 'ABC001' is still available get this, else try 'ABC002' and so on.

One method is to create all codes 'ABC001' to 'ABC999' and then remove the ones already in the table. From these take the least one.

You can use any method to generate your numbers or even have a table containing all allowed codes. Here I use binary math to create the numbers:

```
select min(code) as new_code
from
(
  select concat('ABC', lpad(num,3,'0')) as code
  from
  (
    select a.x + b.x * 2 + c.x * 4 + d.x * 8 + e.x * 16 + f.x * 32 +
           g.x * 64 + h.x * 128 + i.x * 256 + j.x * 512 as num
    from (select 0 as x union all select 1) a
    cross join (select 0 as x union all select 1) b
    cross join (select 0 as x union all select 1) c
    cross join (select 0 as x union all select 1) d
    cross join (select 0 as x union all select 1) e
    cross join (select 0 as x union all select 1) f
    cross join (select 0 as x union all select 1) g
    cross join (select 0 as x union all select 1) h
    cross join (select 0 as x union all select 1) i
    cross join (select 0 as x union all select 1) j
  ) numbers
  where num between 1 and 999
) codes
where code not in (select id from products);
```

Apart from this, I'd fix the bad database design. Store 'ABC' separately from the number. And if it's always 'ABC', don't store that string at all.

Comment: I'd like to test this answer but I'm having a little trouble understanding it. Is there not something I can add or change to the query I already have? If not, am I changing the `codes`, `code`, and `new_code`.. if so what are those changed to? Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seemed to work! I just wanted the 1, instead of ABC001 but this works great and actually skips me a step in PHP. What would I change if I had lets just say `ABC101, ABC103, ABC104` and wanted a result of `ABC102`.. `ABC1` being the first part and `02` being the second part.

Comment: Well, you'd already get 'ABC102' with the query. And you can always use `SUBSTR` to get parts of a string.

Comment: Just testing more, I'm assuming changing the `999` to `99` and the `num,3, '0'` to `num,2, '0'` and the `ABC` to `ABC1` should do the trick?

Comment: The main part of my query simply generates codes. With `where num between 1 and 999` I say which numbers I want, with `concat('ABC', lpad(num,3,'0'))` I create the codes from them. Adjust the two, if you want other or less codes. So with your changes you would only allow ABC100 to ABC199.

Comment: "So with your changes you would only allow ABC100 to ABC199" thats exactly what I want for other products as the highest they will go is 199. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If it's just the biggest used ID plus 1 you are looking for:

```
select concat('ABC', lpad(coalesce(max(substr(id, 4, 3)), 0) + 1, 3, '0')) as new_id
from products;
```